# Lazy object returned unexpected type. error while authentication to admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I m trying to use [All-Auth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for social authentication.

After loading its required settings to my app settings.py, I have to enter admin page to enter Social Tokens.

as soon as I logged in the admin page. it gives me this error:

```
Environment:

    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
    
    Django Version: 1.5
    Python Version: 2.7.1
    Installed Applications:
    ('django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'main',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount')
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
    
    Traceback:
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
    
    response = callback(request, *callbackargs, **callback_kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
    return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in index
    app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['name']) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in lt
    other = other.cast() File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __cast
    return self.text_cast() File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __text_cast
    return func(*self.args, **self.kw) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/text.py" in
    capfirst = lambda x: x and forcetext(x)[0].upper() + force_text(x)[1:] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __wrapper
    raise TypeError("Lazy object returned unexpected type.")
    Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/
    Exception Value: Lazy object returned unexpected type
```

What should I do for solving this problem and Why I get exception?
Any help or idea will be appreciated.
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

the function there that is forcing text to what... unicode?... is forcetext(x) in one case and force_text(x) in 2nd case. In one case it probably returns error message as method does not exist...

Alan